# Why doesn't webscraping work in python while R works without problems?

Tags: python, r

I am webscraping abstract from papers
The following code of R works without any problem.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304393222001441"
page <- read_html(url)
abstract_author <- html_node(imdb,xpath = '//*[@class="abstract author"]')
html_text(abstract_author)
```

Using the same does now work in python

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304393222001441"
response = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
abstract_author = tree.xpath('//*[@class="abstract author"]')[0]
text = abstract_author.text_content()
```

I got the error "IndexError: list index out of range". I looks like it does not find the text in the object

Is there any alternative with python? I tried using headers but no solution

Comment: "I can't make it work in any way" may not be specific enough for people to help you. Do you get errors? Do you get results but they are wrong? What's the first step where the result is different from what you expect?